# Looking for a simple MP3 library for C#

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, multimedia

I'm writing a larger project and a part of the project is playing MP3 files. Nothing fancy, just playing files from a playlist, start/stop, next/previous (can be done outside the library), fast forward/rewind. I'm looking for a (free) library, or any other method of doing that. Relying on an external player is not an option.

Comment: Keep in mind that MP3 is patented by Fraunhofer, so if you want to use it in a commercial application you will have to pay licensing fees. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing_and_patent_issues

Comment: If you use this class it will rely on MediaPlayer, can you explain why that's not an option? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bass Audio Library](http://www.un4seen.com/) is one option.

Check out SDL.NET
http://cs-sdl.sourceforge.net/
It's a library and has ways to play music.

[NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio) is an open source .NET audio library that can play back WAV files, using ACM codecs installed on your computer for decompression purposes. It also has preliminary support for MP3 file playback (works good with CBR, not always so reliably with VBR). It can't do WMA and OGG yet though.

Comment: the problems with VBR in NAudio have been fixed in latest code

Answer (score 3):

You can find a very simple C# library that plays MP3 audio files at:

[A Simple C# Player MP3 with NAudio](http://www.pianetacodice.it/en/2012/10/14/un-semplice-player-mp3-con-naudio-csharp/)

The library have the following functionality:

- Full control over the implementation of the audio file (load, play, stop and pause)
- Volume control audio level and balance of sound.
- Indication of the execution time