# C# listening live stream

Tags: c#, mp3, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I am trying to create a radio player, but i can't listen live stream.

The stream is mp3, but how can I read and play it.
Need a library, for playing mp3 stream?
Can you show sample code?
Thank you for your helping.

Comment: Looks like this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532033/looking-for-a-simple-mp3-library-for-c-sharp

Comment: What is the form factor of your application (webforms, mvc, winforms, wpf)?

Comment: Following links should help:-

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025626/playing-a-mp3-file-in-a-winform-application
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502311/how-to-play-a-sound-in-c-net

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar. I had used [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) for playing MP3. This uses HTML5 internally.

Had some issue with Chrome but solved it. I have posted it on  http://learningsfromdotnet.blogspot.com/2011/11/playing-mp3-using-audio-tag-html-5-in.html

Hope this helps.